# How to run GNAT Community?

Tags: ide, ada, gnat

I've installed Ada Community into desired directory and can't make it run.
There are lot of executable files in the bin directory, tried a lot of them.
[Here is my GNAT directory.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqlAC.png)

Comment: There should be "gnat-gps" in the bin folder. If you don't like that, use your preferred editor and "gnatmake my_program.adb" should do. (If Adacore has dropped gnatmake, use gprbuild instead.)

Comment: Seen elsewhere today, possibly relevant : "Unfortunately,   the  Adacore community 2020 edition doesn't include gps so I am currently using the community 2020 tool-chain and gps from community 2019."  I haven't verified this, but it seems you may have to install an older gps (or on Debian/Ubuntu) "apt-get install gnat-gps" to get the IDE. Apparently that comment refers to Mac; on Windows it may be renamed gnatstudio...

Comment: Looks as though you’ve installed the RISC-V ELF 32 bit cross compiler. You need the x86 GNU Linux (64 bit) version.

Comment: Is your `bin` directory in your path? It has to be in your path, and before any other path that contains a version of gcc.

Comment: @Brian Drummond that's correct I didn't find gps in there, though installer script told to run it. `apt install gnat-gps` does it, thanks.

Comment: @Simon Wright right, thanks.